# Different conditions in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select sum(case when status='qualififed' then 1 else 0 end ) as touched,
sum(case status='Disqualififed' then 1 else 0 end ) as invalid
from lead
```

I have 2 different conditions in both cases.

Conditions are like where substatus in ('lead','opp') for touched
and for invalid - where substatus in ('incomplete','inprogress','open')

How to implement both conditions in the same query??

Comment: Just add your conditions? `case when condition1 and/or condition2 and/or condition3 then X else Y end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this

```
select sum(case when status='qualififed' and substatus in ('lead','opp')  then 1 else 0 end ) as touched,
sum(case status='Disqualififed' and substatus in ('incomplete','inprogress','open') then 1 else 0 end ) as invalid
from lead
```